# How can I take care that my ruby code is encrypted and invisible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My product needs to be deployed and installed on the client's server. How can I take care that my ruby code is encrypted and invisible

Answer (score 2):

You can't. In order to execute the code, the CPU needs to understand the code. CPUs are much stupider than humans, so if the CPU can understand the code, then so can a human.

There are only two possibilities:

1. Don't give your client the code. (The "Google" model.) Instead, give them a *service* that runs your code *under your control*.
2. Give your client a sealed box. (The "XBox" model.) Give your client the code, pre-installed on a hardened, tamper-proof, secure computer under your control, running hardened, tamper-proof, secure firmware under your control, and a hardened, tamper-proof, secure OS under your control. Note that this is non-trivial: Microsoft employed some of the most brilliant hardware security, information security, and cryptography experts on the planet, and they still made a mistake that made the XBox easy to crack.

Unfortunately, you have excluded both those possibilities, so the answer is: you can't.

Note, however, that copying your code is illegal. So, if you don't do business with criminals, then it may not even be necessary to protect your code.

Here are some examples how other companies solve this problem:

- Have a good relationship with your clients. People are less likely to steal from friends they like than from strangers they don't know, or people they actively dislike.
- Make the product so good that clients *want* to pay.
- Make the product so cheap that clients have no incentive to copy the code.
- Offer additional values that you cannot get by copying the code, e.g. support, services, maintenance, training, customization, and consulting.
- Especially in the corporate world, clients often prefer to pay, simply for having someone to sue in case something goes wrong. (You can see this as a special case of the last point.)

Note that copy protection schemes are not free. You at least have to integrate it into your product, which takes developer time and resources. And this assumes that the protection scheme itself is gratis, which is typically not the case. These are either pretty expensive, or you have to develop your own (which is also pretty expensive because experienced cryptographers and infosec specialists are not cheap, and cheap cryptographers and infosec specialists will not be able to create a secure system.)

This in turn increases the price of your product, which makes it more likely that someone can't afford it and will copy it.

Also, I have *never* seen a copy protection scheme that works. There's always something wrong with them. The hardware dongle is only available with an interface the client doesn't have. (For example, when computers stopped having serial and parallel ports in favor of USB, a lot of copy protection schemes still required serial or parallel ports and didn't work with USB-to-serial or USB-to-parallel adapters.) Or, the client uses a VM, so *there is no hardware* to plug the dongle into. Or, the copyright protection scheme requires Internet access, but that is not available. Or, the driver of the dongle crashes the client's machine. Or, the license key contains characters that can't easily by typed on the client's keyboard. Or, the copy protection scheme has a bug that doesn't allow non-ASCII characters, but you are using the client's name as part of the key. Or, the manufacturer of the copy protection scheme changes the format of dongle to an incompatible one without telling you, and without changing the type number, or the color and physical form of the dongle, so you don't notice.

Note that none of this is hypothetical: all of these have happened to me as a user. Several of these happened at vendors I know.

This means that a there will be significant amount of resources needed in your support department to deal with those problems, which increases the cost of your product even further. It also decreases client satisfaction, when they have problems with your product. (Again, I know some companies that use copy protection and get a significant amount of support tickets because of that.)

There are industries where it is quite common that people buy the product, but then use a cracked version anyway because the copyright protection schemes are *so bad* that the risk of losing your data due to a cracked version from an untrusted source is *lower* than losing your data due to the badly implemented copyright protection scheme.

There is a company that is very successful, and very loved by its users that does not use any copy protection in a market where *everybody* uses copy protection. This is how *they* do it:

- Because they don't have to invest development resources into copy protection, their products are at least as good as their competition's for less development effort.
- Because they don't have to invest development resources into copy protection, their products are cheaper than their competition's.
- Because their product are not burdened with the overhead of copy protection, their products are more stable and more efficient than their competition's.
- They have fair pricing, based on income levels in their target countries, meaning they charge lower prices in poorer countries. This makes it less likely that someone copies their product because they can't afford it.
- A single license can be used on as many machines as you like, both Windows and macOS.
- There is a no-questions-asked, full-refund return policy.
- The lead-developer and the lead-designer personally respond to every single support issue, feature request, and enhancement suggestion.

Of course, they know full well that people abuse their return policy. They buy the product, use it for a project, then give it back. But, they have received messages from people saying "Hey, I copied your software and used it in a project. During this project, I realized how awesome your software is, here's your money, and here's something extra as an apology. Also, I showed it to my friends and colleagues, and they all bought a copy!"

Another example are switch manufacturers. Most of them have very strict license enforcement. However, one of them goes a different route: there is one version of the firmware, and it always has all features enabled. Nothing bad will happen if you use features that you haven't paid for. However, when you need support, they will compare your config to your account, and then say "Hey, we noticed that you are using some features you haven't paid for. We are sure that this is an honest mistake on your part, so we will help you this once, but please don't forget to send us a purchase order as soon as possible, thanks!"

Guess which manufacturer I prefer to work with, and prefer to recommend?